# Attribute return of a function to an array

Tags: c, pointers, return, malloc

this is my first question on StackOverflow ! :)
To be honest I'm about to destroy my whole setup.

My code is making me crazy.

My problem is, I am not able to fill a dynamic array with the return of a function.
My goal here is, for each array box, fill it with a random value of 'randomizer'. I am not able to take the return of randomizer in the array box.

Here is the code:

**main.c**:

```
#include "functions.h"
#include "functions.c"

/*       TP 3 - ESIEE-IT Rémy JARDIN        */

int main() {
    int saisie, i;
    printf("Creation du Tableau. \nNombre de caractere du tableau : ");
    scanf("%d", &saisie);
    ArrayCreate(saisie);
     
    // Affichage
    
    return 0;
}
```

**functions.h**:

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int ArrayCreate(int saisie);
int randomizer();
int insereAIndice();

#endif
```

**functions.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    
int ArrayCreate(int saisie) {
    int i;
    int *Tab = (int *)malloc(saisie * sizeof(int));
    if (Tab == NULL) {
        printf("Not enough Memory");
        exit (1);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < saisie; i++) {
        Tab[i] = (randomizer + 1);
    }
    
    printf("\n Resultats : ");
    for (i = 0; i < saisie; i++) {
        printf("%d - ", *(Tab + i));
    }
    
    return 0;
}
    
int randomizer() {
    //int x = rand() % (100 + 1);
    return 1;
}
```

And the error is:

```
functions.c: In function 'ArrayCreate':
functions.c:12:8: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 Tab[i] = (randomizer+1);
```

Comment: `randomizer` is a function. You use it as a variable. You need to call the function.

Comment: On another (but unrelated) note, in C you [don't have to (and really shouldn't) cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/).

Comment: Oh, and don't `#include` source files. If you want a project with multiple source file you should build them one by one and then *link* them together into the executable program file.

Comment: All in all, with the problem you have, the mixed use of array indexing (as arrays and as pointers) including a source file, the casting of the `malloc` result, and a couple of other minor details, it makes me suspect you're not using a very good source to learn C. What resources *are* you using?

Comment: Thank you ! However, what do you mean by "don't #include source files" ?

Comment: You have `#include "functions.c"`. That's not the correct way to do projects using multiple source files.

Comment: Oh I see, I should use a makefile right ?

Comment: @Rémyjardin: so the argument is *readability*... The most important here is consistency. You can either use `int *Tab = (int *)malloc(saisie * sizeof(int));` or `int *Tab = malloc(saisie * sizeof(*Tab));`  The latter is simpler and does not need to be modified if you later change the type of `Tab`.

Comment: With larger, projects tools similar to `make` are really needed. There are meta-build tools which can generate makefiles (or files for other build-systems) for you, like CMake and Meson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Tab[i] = (randomizer + 1);` you should write:

```
Tab[i] = randomizer();
```

Note also these remarks:

- the function prototypes in **functions.h** should have an argument of `void`:

  ```
  int randomizer(void);
  int insereAIndice(void);
  ```
- file **functions.c** should include **functions.h** to ensure consistency between function declarations and definitions.
- Writing `*(Tab + i)` is much less readable than `Tab[i]`. If you wish to obfuscate the code, use `i[Tab]` which is equivalent :)

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "functions.h"

int ArrayCreate(int saisie) {
    int i;
    int *Tab = (int *)malloc(saisie * sizeof(int));
    if (Tab == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Not enough Memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < saisie; i++) {
        Tab[i] = randomizer();
    }
    
    printf("\n Resultats : ");
    for (i = 0; i < saisie; i++) {
        printf(" %d", Tab[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
    
int randomizer(void) {
    // return a random integer in the range 1..100
    return 1 + rand() % 100;
}
```

Comment: @Rémyjardin: thanks! 290 points today! my best score in 7 years.